# spring 5 How do I send a parameter with a .json suffix in the @pathvariable

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc, spring-annotations

I have a service that receives "long" as a parameter type, but sending the parameter with the .json suffix does not resolve it and I take it as if it were a "string" . For example, if I send "1017.json" it takes as if the parameter to be sent was a String and not a long one.

This is the service

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping("changeProblem/{treatmentPlanGridId}")
public List<DropDownDTO> changeProblem(@PathVariable(value = "treatmentPlanGridId") long 
treatmentPlanGridId)
        throws ControllerException {
    List<DropDownDTO> subProblemDTOList = new ArrayList<DropDownDTO>();
    LocalDate activeDate = new LocalDate();
```

In my dispatcher add the suffix property but it still didn't work

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">


 <mvc:annotation-driven content-negotiation-manager="cnManager" />

<context:annotation-config />

<!-- In the dispatcher context, we should only include classes annotated with the @Controller annotation -->
<context:component-scan base-package="com.qualifacts.carelogic" use-default-filters="false">
    <!-- this should only load controllers and their support components. all other spring beans are loaded by the parent app context -->
    <context:include-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller" />
    <context:include-filter type="annotation" expression="com.qualifacts.carelogic.ControllerSupport" />
    <context:include-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ControllerAdvice" />
</context:component-scan>





<mvc:interceptors>
    <mvc:interceptor>
        <mvc:mapping path="/client/ecr/**"/>
        <bean class="com.qualifacts.carelogic.client.ECRInterceptor"/>
    </mvc:interceptor>
    <mvc:interceptor>
        <mvc:mapping path="/svcdoc/document/pdfgenerator/**"/>
        <bean class="com.qualifacts.carelogic.svcdoc.pdf.PDFGeneratorInterceptor"/> 
    </mvc:interceptor>
</mvc:interceptors>

<bean id="xmlViewResolver" class="com.qualifacts.carelogic.spring.XmlViewResolver">
    <qualifier value="xmlResolver"></qualifier>
    <property name="delegate" ref="jspViewResolver"/>
</bean>

<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver">
    <property name="order" value="1"/>
    <property name="contentNegotiationManager" ref="cnManager"/>
    <property name="viewResolvers">
        <list>
            <!-- xslt view resolver handles xml -> html view translation -->
            <bean class="com.qualifacts.carelogic.spring.XsltViewResolver">
                <property name="delegate" ref="jspViewResolver"/>
            </bean>
            <!-- reportgen view resolver handles xml -> pdf view translation -->
            <bean class="com.qualifacts.carelogic.spring.ReportgenViewResolver">
                <property name="delegate" ref="jspViewResolver"/>
            </bean>
            <!-- xml view resolver writes the raw xml to output -->
            <ref bean="xmlViewResolver"/>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="defaultViews">
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJackson2JsonView">
                <property name="objectMapper">
                    <bean class="com.qualifacts.carelogic.spring.CustomObjectMapper"/>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="cnManager" class="org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="favorPathExtension" value="true"/>
    <property name="useJaf" value="false"/>
    <property name="mediaTypes">
        <map>
            <entry key="html" value="text/html" />
            <entry key="pdf" value="application/pdf" />
            <entry key="xml" value="text/xml" />
            <entry key="json" value="application/json" /> 
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="jspViewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="order" value="2"/>
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    <property name="redirectContextRelative" value="false"/>
    <property name="redirectHttp10Compatible" value="false" />
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping">
    <property name="useSuffixPatternMatch" value="true"/>
</bean>


<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
```

**I am using spring 5. How can I make it so that when I send the pathvariable parameter 1017.json it only takes the value 1017?**

/problems/changeProblem/1017.json

Comment: You should change `treatmentPlanGridId`'s type from `long` to `String`, because `1017.json` is not an integer

Comment: Hi @NikolaiShevchenko  thank for your answer.  Before updating the version of spring 3 to 5 it worked. It sent the parameter with the suffix and spring interpreted that the response was a json and only took the parameter and not the .json extension.

Answer (score 1):

`1017.json` is a `String` and not a number so `String` is right. Basically sending a string with a number inside and expecting that Spring does not complain about it is poor design. There is a reason why we have data types.
Get the parameter as a `String` variable and then remove all the non digits if they are not needed. Like this:

```java
yourParameter = yourParameter.replaceAll("[^\\d]",""); // replace all non digit characters with ""

// Convert your string into an integer:
int integerValueOfParameter = Integer.parse(yourParameter);
```

Comment: Hi Renis1235 thank for your answer. Before updating the version of spring 3 to 5 it worked. It sent the parameter with the suffix and spring interpreted that the response was a json and only took the parameter and not the .json extension

Comment: Trust me @monjeloco, you do not want that. You have to be sure of what you are sending. If you send a `string` it is a `string` and not a camouflaged `integer`.